# Get the count after joining many to many relationship tables

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, dbcontext

I have two tables Countries and Regions. These tables do name mapping between two systems. I need to get the number of matching records count for the given two tables where there is a condition for each tables item selection

```
public class Region
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string System_A_Name { get; set; }
    public string System_B_Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Country> Countries { get; set; }
}

public class Country
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string System_A_Name { get; set; }
    public string System_B_Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Region> Regions { get; set; }
}
```

Through the program I get some values, which I need to verify if its available in the records.

```
repository.Regions.Join(repository.Countries, r => r.System_A_Name == "North America_A", c => c.System_B_Name == "Canada");
```

I need to get the count of the result to check if there are valid records as such. How to do this ?

Comment: Can't you just put a `.Count()` at the end of your statement? Or you write `var myStatement = /* ... */; int cnt = myStatement.Count()`

Comment: i believe your code doesn't compile? am i correct? added an answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i believe your `join` statement is not compiling

try this

```
var joined = repository.Regions
                   .Join(repository.Countries, 
                         r => r.Id, //common attribute to base join
                         c => c.Id, //common attribute to base join
                        (r, c) => new { Region = r, Country = c}) //selector for your joined statmenet
//your conditions
                   .Where(joinedRegAndCountry => 
                              joinedRegAndCountry.Region.System_A_Name == "North America_A" &&
                              joinedRegAndCountry.Country.System_B_Name == "Canada")
                             .Count();
```

Comment: LIorico actually it didn't compile as i have missed the last parameter. Could please shed some light why "(r, c) => new { Region = r, Country = c}" is used ?

Comment: @sm101 also i noticed my code, what is the key for region = to key of country?

Comment: in the where clause (joinedRegAndCountry.Region.System_A_Name == "North America_A", joinedRegAndCountry.Country.System_B_Name == "Canada") the comma gave me an issue I added && as (joinedRegAndCountry.Region.System_A_Name == "North America_A" && joinedRegAndCountry.Country.System_B_Name == "Canada"). That worked.

Comment: @sm101 sorry, typo, if it did help, hoping you could mark it as helpful and as answer